# In my data-provider addFieldtoFilter() is not working with url param

Tags: magento2, admin, collection, grid

I have made a grid in admin that is supposed to return a filtered collection based on a URL parameter **lesson_id**.

**DataProvider:**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Ui\DataProvider\Participants;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;
use VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Participants\CollectionFactory;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{

    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        Http $request,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
    }

    public function getData(){
        $lessonId = $this->request->getParam('lesson_id');

        if (!$this->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('lesson_id',['eq' => $lessonId]);
            $this->getCollection()->load();
        }

        return $this->getCollection()->toArray();
    }
}
```

When i var_dump() the Array with **lesson_id**=7 from the URL it returns:

```
array(2) { ["totalRecords"]=> int(1) ["items"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(7) { ["participant_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["lesson_id"]=> string(1) "7" ["customer_id"]=> string(2) "98" ["name"]=> string(8) "test 420" ["completed"]=> string(1) "1" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2022-10-06 08:41:52" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2022-10-07 10:28:35" } } }
```

However the grid does not display the entry.
But now i replace the **lesson_id** in addFieldToFilter with a normal int or string like so:

```
$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('lesson_id',7);
```

The var_dump() shows the **exact** same array but this time the entry **does** get displayed in grid without problems.
So i have two questions, the first is what causes this and the second is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for posterity:
i still dont know why the URL param gets lost in the data source but i have found a workaround.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Participants;

use Magento\Backend\Model\Session;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function __construct(
        Session $backendSession
    ) {
        $this->backendSession = $backendSession;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->backendSession->setTokenId($this->test->getUrlParam('lesson_id'));

    }
}
```

here we get the URL param in the grid controller and store it in the back end session.

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Ui\DataProvider\Participants;

use VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Participants\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Session;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{

    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        Session $backendSession,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
        $this->backendSession = $backendSession;
    }

    public function getData(){
        if (!$this->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('lesson_id',['eq' => $this->backendSession->getTokenId()]);
            $this->getCollection()->load();
        }

        return $this->getCollection()->toArray();
    }
}
```

and now we retrieve the url param from the session in the data-provider and now the filter is applied properly.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the exact answer you are looking for, but filtering by url params is already supported by the datasource component without creating a custom class.

By adding the filterUrlParams as part of the settings, like this:

```
<dataSource name="test_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
    <settings>
        <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        <filterUrlParams>
            <param name="lesson_id">*</param>
        </filterUrlParams>
    </settings>
    ....
</dataSource>
```

So there is a good chance you can solve it a lot easier.

Comment: Yes i tried that first but that did not filter anything i just got the full database table displayed in grid.